# Photoshop script to swich path operations?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, script

Is there script which allows me to set and use one path operation and switch it to another?

I need to use "combine shapes", later I need to use "subtract front shape". So I need to switch them. But how?

Recorded action, scrip listener = no results.

There is some info about path operations in:

[Photoshop Scripting Refernce](https://theiviaxx.github.io/photoshop-docs/Photoshop/ShapeOperation.html?highlight=shapeoperation%20shapeadd)

...but I was not able to make it work.

Comment: You have to iterate over the path and reset each point. The answer is [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/change-shape-operation-on-path/m-p/14251704#M766671)